# photo collage : how to achieve multiple grid type views in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to create a photo collage app in android. I don't know where to start. If anyone can help me the way i can achieve this. I think it uses three views in a single layout but i don't understand how to achieve photo collage. I created an app where i used a single zoom view whole screen and which has pan zoom too.

```
<com.simpleapps.sceneryphotoframes.zoom.ImageZoomView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/zoomview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/>
```

But that was for one view. I want to know how to do that for multiple photos.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Was Simple, for any one wondering..

I just Added multiple custom views.

```
 <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/parentviewLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.simpleapps.photocollage.PanZoomView
android:id="@+id/zoomview1"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<com.simpleapps.photocollage.PanZoomView1
android:id="@+id/zoomview2"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<com.simpleapps.photocollage.PanZoomView2
android:id="@+id/zoomview3"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```